# Cannot get result while I use Alamofire

Tags: swift

I am using Alamofire version 3.1.5 with my xCode version 7.3. I tried it on many apps of mine. But I do not get any result. No error is seen before the execution. My code is like this:

```
var apiUrl : String
var alamoFireManager:Manager!
var configuration = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
init(apiUrl : String){
        self.apiUrl = apiUrl
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0
        alamoFireManager = Alamofire.Manager(configuration: configuration)
    }
print(apiUrl)
alamoFireManager.request(.GET, apiUrl, encoding: .JSON).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]) .responseJSON { response in
            print(response.result.value)
            switch response.result{
            case .Success:
                if let value = response.result.value{
                    let json = JSON(value)
                    print (json)
                    callback.onResponse(value) // this is where my value is sent
                }
            case .Failure(let error):
                print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
```

I checked using breakpoint and the app directly reaches this last braces frm the alamofire line.

Comment: Does the `print(response.result.value)` eventually get reached?

Comment: No, it doesn't. from the line with alamofireManager it directly goes to the end braces

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is you are not calling `resume()`. From the Alamofire doc

> If the owning manager does not have startRequestsImmediately set to
>   true, the request must call resume() in order to start.

try this

```
alamoFireManager.request(.GET, apiUrl, encoding: .json).validate(contentType: ["application/json"]).resume().responseJSON { response in
        print(response.result.value)
        switch response.result{
        case .Success:
            if let value = response.result.value{
                let json = JSON(value)
                print (json)
                callback.onResponse(value) // this is where my value is sent
            }
        case .Failure(let error):
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i get this error again when i call resume "Value of tuple type '()' has no member responseJSON". Well thank you